# Prove if f is differentiable with minimum c, then f'(c)=0

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Prove that if $f$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$ and attains a minimum at $c$ on $(a,b)$, then $f'(c) = 0.$

I understand the concept for attempting it with Fermat's Theorem, but I'm not sure how to go about writing it as a proof?

I'm also told there is a proof using Mean Value Theorem but I've not yet covered that, could anyone maybe run through that with me?

Comment: Use the definition of $f'(c)$ as a limit, and examine the resulting quotient.

Comment: @Mathisishard : the Mean Value Theorem is unnecessary, and overkill for this problem.  The standard proof of the MVT uses Rolle's Theorem, the proof of which uses the exact fact that you are trying to prove here, so I think applying the MVT to this problem is inappropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ be another point in $(a, b)$ and look at difference quotients.

**Case** $c < x < b$:  Since $f$ has a local minimum at $x = c$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
x - c &> 0 \\
f(x) - f(c) &> 0
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x - c} > 0
$$
and so
$$
\lim_{x \to c^+} \frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x - c} \ge 0.
$$

**Case** $a < x < c$:  By an analogous argument, we can show that
$$
\lim_{x \to c^-} \frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x - c} \le 0.
$$

Now, using the hypothesis that the derivative exists at $x = c$, the one-sided limits must agree, so
$$
0 \le f'(c) \le 0,
$$
which implies that
$$
f'(c) = 0.
$$

Comment: Two small issues: 1. You are using that $c$ is a minimum, not a local minimum. For the argument to work for local minima, your $x$ cannot be arbitrary, but needs to be restricted to a suitable neighborhood of $c$. 2. You left out the possibility that $f(x)=f(c)$ for all $x$ near $c$. This is trivial, of course, but needs addressing.

Comment: You are correct on both counts, Andres.  I should have first chosen a neighborhood $(a_1, b_1)$ around $c$.  Then the argument works *mutatis mutandis.*